# Make change inside app.config() in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-scope

I am using googlePlace api in angularJs and I want to change type of places dynamically as needed. Like I use controllers to bind the values in view part using $scope but it's not working in this situation also tried $rootScope.

Tried many other things too but they all are not working and I'm also new to angularJs so don't know much.

Here is code:-

```js
app.config(function(ngGPlacesAPIProvider){
  ngGPlacesAPIProvider.setDefaults({
    radius:1000000,
 types:['electronics_store','bakery','bank','beauty_salon','bicycle_store','book_store','cafe','car_dealer','car_wash','car_repair','clothing_store','dentist','department_store'],
 nearbySearchKeys: ['name','geometry', 'reference'],
 placeDetailsKeys: ['name','formatted_address', 'formatted_phone_number',
        'reference', 'website', 'geometry', 'email'],
  });
});
```

Controller code:-

```js
  app.config(function(ngGPlacesAPIProvider, ngGPlacesDefaults){
   ngGPlacesAPIProvider.setDefaults(ngGPlacesDefaults);
 });

app.controller('scdfindCustomerCtrl',function($scope,ngGPlacesAPI,$http,ngGPlacesDefaults){

   ngGPlacesDefaults.types = ["atm"];
 
 $scope.getDetails = function(ref){
  $scope.details = ngGPlacesAPI.placeDetails({reference:ref}).then(
       function (data) {
        $scope.det=data;
         console.log(data);
         return data;
       });
 }
 
 $scope.positions = [{lat:37.7699298,lng:-122.4469157}];
 
 $scope.addMarker = function(event) {
    var ll = event.latLng;
  
    $scope.positions.push({lat:ll.lat(), lng: ll.lng()});
  
 
 $scope.data = ngGPlacesAPI.nearbySearch({latitude:ll.lat(), longitude:ll.lng()}).then(
    function(data){
  $scope.person=data;
  console.log(data);
   return data;
    });
}
```

So basically I want to change "types:[]" array from view part.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could have those set of default values as an constant, so that you could get those value inside config phase directly, as angular `constant`s are accessible over there & in all other component of angular like `controller`, `factory`, `directive`, etc just by injecting dependency of it.

**Constant**

```
app.constant('ngGPlacesDefaults', {
    radius:1000000,
    types:['electronics_store','bakery','bank','beauty_salon','bicycle_store','book_store','cafe','car_dealer','car_wash','car_repair','clothing_store','dentist','department_store'],
    nearbySearchKeys: ['name','geometry', 'reference'],
    placeDetailsKeys: ['name','formatted_address', 'formatted_phone_number',
        'reference', 'website', 'geometry', 'email'],
  });
})
```

**Config**

```
app.config(function(ngGPlacesAPIProvider, ngGPlacesDefaults){
  ngGPlacesAPIProvider.setDefaults(ngGPlacesDefaults);
});
```

Whenever you wanted to change the value of `ngGPlacesDefaults` configuration, you can have handle to those value by injecting `ngGPlacesDefaults` dependency

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, ngGPlacesDefaults){
  //other code here

  ngGPlacesDefaults.types = ["some", "different", "values"]; //you could change value like this
})
```

Comment: I added that "constant part" in my app.js file and left "types:[] array " blank. 
now I am trying to set the value of types array in my controller let's say type: "atm" but it's not showing list of atms.

Comment: @Anonymous you need to follow the same step which I did in answer..It would be something like `ngGPlacesDefaults.types = ["atms"];`

Comment: It seems like It's loading the values before initialisation in  controller.

Comment: @Anonymous can you add some code..how you are calling `ngGPlacesAPI` methods inside your controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94472/discussion-between-anonymous-and-pankaj-parkar).

Answer (score 0):

I found a different way to solve this problem. You don't need to extra just pass the types:[] as an argument in 'nearBySearch' function

```js
$scope.data = ngGPlacesAPI.nearbySearch({latitude:ll.lat(), longitude:ll.lng(), types:[$scope.business.selected.businessType]}).then(
    function(data){
  $scope.person=data;
  console.log(data);
   return data;
    });
```

"$scope.business.selected.businessType" is bindable dynamically from view, that's it.