# How can I change default values inside config file in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, google-places-api

https://github.com/arunisrael/angularjs-google-places

I want to change this default values dynamically but don't know how to do?

I tried to define constant but they can't be changed.
I also tried values but they can't be injected inside config file.

So any one can tell me how can i change types:[] array from controller in angularJs?

Any help would be much appreciated !!

Comment: Is it related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/33579811/2435473 ?

Comment: constants aren't really constants if they are reference types. If they are value types, then yes, I agree they cannot be changed.

Comment: I think you need to set that `types` property again while calling API method..

Comment: Well I guess this is very obvious thing which came to my mind but I am looking for question "How" ?

Comment: @pixelbits yes I do agree with you but in that Q they were using as value type.

Comment: The `ngGPlacesAPI` provider has a set defaults function. Why not expose that and then call it to change the defaults>

Comment: @brianlmerritt I'm actually new to this, Could you please elaborate little more?

Comment: You can try overriding the default by changing the parameters ngGPlacesAPI. default[parameterName]  = "avalue" or maybe  .default.parameterName =

Comment: Sorry, this is off the cuff from a mobile. Hopefully someone else will come to rescue if you are still stuck. Look for a service config function on the main service or look at other similar code and add a config function.

Comment: ohh thanks for your kind gestures !! I'm trying may be by tomorrow I will figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes earlier I was looking for same problem then I created an issue in main repo and also wrote an answer. Please have look I guess It will solve your problem.

https://github.com/arunisrael/angularjs-google-places/issues/17